# How to call code behind function in success junction of AJAX

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'm consuming a web service using ajax in web form 3.5, then save it to database. I'm getting a success response from the web service. However, how will I call my code behind function to save the data after success in ajax? I'm new to ajax.

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id ="divName" runat="server" class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label">Name</label>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" CssClass="form-control" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
            </div>
    <input id="btnRegister" type="button" value="Register" /><br />
    </form>
    <script type ="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnRegister").click(function () {
                debugger;
                var namee = document.getElementById("<%=txtname.ClientID %>").value;
                Register(namee);
            });

            function Register(name) {
                debugger;
                var id = 
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "https://webservice.com/register",
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        "name": name
                    }),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    datatype: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        //call code behind function in saving data.
                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert("ERROR");
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Are you aware you can call the webservice in your code behind using a traditional post? If you want to call your codebehind client side you need to set it up as a WebMethod and then call that using AJAX as well.

Comment: Also note in ASP.net these are know as PageMethods, more info here: https://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=109

Comment: @JonP, Yes I'm aware of that, but I have many validation in my code behind so my approach is to separate the consuming of web service, and another function in saving data to my database.

Comment: Validation is good, but why call the webservice at all in a case where validation would fail?

Comment: @JonP, but it is part of the procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you just should to call another ajax again in success section.
like this :

```
function Register(name) {
                debugger;
                var id = 
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "https://webservice.com/register",
                    data: JSON.stringify({
                        "name": name
                    }),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    datatype: "json",
```

> ```
>                    success: function (response) {
>                          MySaveDataFunc(response)
>                     },
> ```

```
                    failure: function (response) {
                        alert("ERROR");
                    }
                });
            }



 var MySaveDataFunc=function(mydata)
    {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "Your SaveData Url",
                        data: mydata
                        contentType: "application/json",
                        datatype: "json",
                        success: function (response) {                         
                        },
                        failure: function (response) {

                        }
                    });  
    }
```

I hope it has been helpful .

Answer (score 0):

Ajax code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: "Registration.aspx/GetData",
        type:"POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#responseContent').text(data.d);
        }

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For these type of problems. It's good to create a separate Js file as it keeps the code clean and understandable. 
And please be more precise with the questions.

From my understanding => if this i.e. "https://webservice.com/register" one sends a success response, you need to save it to say "https://localhost/register" in your own system. 
create a varible url in the global scope of your field and set that url to your ajax req.

```js
var yourUrl = "something";

//on ajax send method
url: yourUrl

//on success method, call the same method but change the url to your new url, this way you save both the time and redundant code
   Register(name,yourUrl); //add a second parameter to take url in your register function
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use shor-hand method of ajax for post request.
**$(selector).post(URL,data,function(data,status,xhr),dataType);**
For Example in your case:

```
$.post(url:"https://webservice.com/register"
      ,data:JSON.stringify({"name": name})
      ,function(data,status,xhr){
      //Your callback function
      //Example: alert(data.Message);
      });
```